# PowerShell dictionary of arrays?

Tags: arrays, powershell, dictionary

In VBScript I can do something like this

```vb
Set objDict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
objDict.Add "item1", Array("data1", "data2")
objDict.Add "item2", Array("data3", "data4")
```

Then I can do a lookup using something like this

```vb
dataArray = objDict.Item("item2")
elem1 = dataArray(0)
elem2 = dataArray(1)
```

the result is `elem1` contains "data3" and `elem2` contains "data4"

I am not sure how to replicate this in PowerShell. Anyone help?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Dictionaries are called hashtables in PowerShell. When PowerShell first came out Microsoft also released a [VBScript-to-PowerShell Conversion Guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-powershell-1.0/ff657834(v=msdn.10)), covering [dictionaries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-powershell-1.0/ff657832(v%3dmsdn.10)) and [arrays](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-powershell-1.0/ee156795(v%3dtechnet.10)) among other things.

You define hashtables (dictionaries) like this:

```
$d = @{
  'foo' = 'something'
  'bar' = 42
}
```

Alternatively –for instance if you need to populate the hashtable dynamically– you can create an empty hashtable and add elements to it, like this:

```
$d = @{}
$d.Add('foo', 'something')
$d.Add('bar', 42)
```

or like this:

```
$d = @{}
$d['foo'] = 'something'
$d['bar'] = 42
```

Usually I prefer the latter, because it replaces existing keys instead of throwing an error.

```
$d1 = @{}
$d1.Add('foo', 23)
$d1.Add('foo', 42)   # can't add another key with same name => error

$d2 = @{}
$d2['foo'] = 23      # key is automatically added
$d2['foo'] = 42      # replaces value of existing key
```

Arrays are defined as a simple comma-separated list:

```
$a = 'a', 'b', 'c'
```

Optionally you can also use the [array subexpression operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators?view=powershell-3.0#special-operators):

```
$a = @('a', 'b', 'c')
```

That's useful if you need an array result, but are unsure of how many results your expression will produce. Without the operator you'd get `$null`, a single value, or an array, depending on the result of the expression. By using the operator you always get an array, with zero, one, or more elements.

Both array and hashtable elements can be accessed via the [index operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators?view=powershell-3.0#special-operators) (`[]`):

```
$d['foo']  # output: "something"
$a[1]      # output: "b"
```

The elements of hashtables can also be accessed via dot-notation:

```
$d.foo     # output: "something"
```

Of course you can nest arrays in hashtables and vice versa, just like you can do in VBScript. Your example would look somewhat like this in PowerShell

```
$dict = @{
  'item1' = 'data1', 'data2'
  'item2' = 'data3', 'data4'
}

$dataArray = $dict['item2']
$elem1 = $dataArray[0]
$elem2 = $dataArray[1]
```

PowerShell has learned a thing or two from other scripting languages, though. For instance you can assign arrays to a list of variables, so the above assignment of array elements to individual variables could be simplified to this:

```
$elem1, $elem2 = $dict['item2']
```

If the array has more elements than the number of variables on the left side of the assignment, the last variable takes the remainder of the array:

```
$x, $y, $z = 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd'
# $x -> 'a'
# $y -> 'b'
# $z -> @('c', 'd')

$x, $y, $z = 'a', 'b'
# $x -> 'a'
# $y -> 'b'
# $z -> $null
```

The index operator allows access to multiple elements:

```
$a = 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'
$a[1,3,4]  # output: "b", "d", "e"
```

as well as elements from the end of the array:

```
$a = 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'
$a[-1]  # output: "e"
$a[-2]  # output: "d"
```

And the [range operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators?view=powershell-3.0#special-operators) (`..`) allows you to get a slice from an array by just specifying the first and last index. It produces a list of numbers starting with the first operand and ending with the second operand (e.g. `2..5`→`2,3,4,5`).

```
$a = 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'
$a[1..3]    # equivalent to $a[1,2,3], output: "b", "c", "d"
$a[-1..-3]  # equivalent to $a[-1,-2,-3], output: "e", "d", "c"
```

Comment: Great overview; worth mentioning: hashtable-literal keys only need quoting if they contain whitespace or metacharacters.

Comment: Worth noting too, `$dictionary.Add("foo", 42)` vs `$d['bar'] = 42` behave very differently because they are very different things.

Comment: @AustinFrench That's what the comments in the respective example were meant to point out.

Answer (score 3):

Another solution, you can use a [System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary](https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/xfhwa508(v=vs.110).aspx) like this:

```
 #for create your dictionary
 $mydico = New-Object 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary[string,string]'

 #For add element into your dictionary
 $mydico.Add("mykey1", "myvalue1") 
 $mydico.Add("mykey2", "myvalue2")

 #for get value by key
 $value = $mydico["mykey1"]   # $value has myvalue1 like value
```